# Why LSTM predicts very poorly with loss curves showing no indication of overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training a LSTM model for load demand prediction with:

Training Data: 18288 samples with 9 features

Validation Data: 0.05% of Training Data (about 915 samples)

Data Scaling: MinMax Scaler(0,1)--->Including the target variable.

Batch size: 1024

Length of Past Data Window: 24~72

Model Architecture: (attached)

Learning Rate: 0.001

Epochs: 100

I am also attaching the snapshot of loss curves and curves showing predictions made again on same validation data set as the one used in model tuning.

- Yeah, I do realize that even I ask the model to predict on the "Exactly Same" dataset, it should ideally give me the perfect forecast but even so please look at the attached forecats curve. Why is this happening?
- The loss curves show no sign of model perforamnce degradation over the training epochs. I also tried increasing the model complexity assuming if model is not complex enough to capture underlying trends but thats no use. I also tried decreasing the validation split(to make sure training data is more representative) further but then validation loss curve goes under the training loss curve.
- One thing I noticed is that target variable in the training data has min: 0 kWh , mean: 40 kWh and max: 162 kWh while for validation data these values are min: 13.472 kWh, mean:48 kWh and max:136 kWh and if look at the forecasts, the maximum amplitude of perfect cyclic pattern with constant amplitude is almost 60kWh.

SO why this might be happeing and how can I get rid of this problem? Also, I dont have additional data for training so there's that.

[image: LSTM Architecture]

[image: Loss Curves]

[image: Model Forecast]

Comment: Do you normalise your data ? (if yes, you need to convert to the original scale after prediction)

Comment: The output shown is de-normalised.

Comment: Is this hourly data? If yes add a weekday feature or increase your window length to 168 ( ie a week)

Comment: Hi! I tried increasing window length to 168 and there is no difference from the above results.

Comment: It could be your architecture. A low loss doesn't guarantee good metrics, as these are often not directly correlated. I'd invest some time in hyper-parameter optimization.